# Struts 2 tiles integration, multiple jsps without refreshing the tiles frames

Tags: struts2, tiles

I am new to tiles. In my current project I am using Struts 2 and tiles. I got the tiles layout and the actions are working fine.

My problem is in my web page I have 3 frames apart from the header and footer,
i.e.-search, list of records, Detailed record.
In search frame I get the search action an the result is shown in list of records, in that frame I am getting list of records, so by clicking a particular record I am showing the complete details of the record in Detailed record frame.

What my problem is when I am trying to call  Detailed record the list of records frame and search getting refreshed and the list of records become empty, but I can see the record details in the Detailed record frame.

Now I want to keep the list of records frame with all records when I am trying to call the record detail view action.

Comment: I find this very confusing... some html might help us.  Have you considered not using frames and using ajax?

Comment: Thanks For the response  Quaternion, i solved the problem by using iframes.

Comment: I'm not sure you're using tiles correctly if your page is full of iframes... "...I have 3 frames apart from the header and footer..." typically a user of tiles would have no iframes not that they are excluded it just not what tiles does. It composes things, what that stuff is is another issue.

Comment: I'm Using only one frame to load my results in side my base layout.. ----"...I have 3 frames apart from the header and footer..." ---it was my mistake. sorry for  confusing you, i am new to blogging will post my next question properly.... Thanks Quaternion